# S3 Put cloudformation lambda trigger

Tags: amazon-s3, triggers, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I need some help writing the cloud formation that would get triggered by S3 put, from reading the documentation I see that you need **NotificationConfiguration** with event and function specified in bucket definition, but I keep getting the error "    Unable to validate the following destination configurations" and it craps out and rollback the update. Can someone take a look at my CF script and identify what I am doing wrong, I think the issue could be in either **NotificationConfiguration** or **rLambdaInvokePermission**, but I am not sure which much appreciated!

here's my yaml:

```
Resources:
  rAppBucketS3Policy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref rS3bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          # SSL access enforced
            - Sid: EnforceSecureTransport
              Action: s3:*
              Effect: Deny
              Principal: '*'
              Resource: !Join ["",[ "arn:aws:s3:::", Ref: rS3bucket, '/*' ] ]
              Condition:
                Bool:
                  aws:SecureTransport: 'false'
            - Sid: EnforceEncryptionOnPut
              Effect: Deny
              Principal: '*'
              Action: s3:PutObject
              Resource: !Join ["",[ "arn:aws:s3:::", Ref: rS3bucket, '/*' ] ]
              Condition:
                StringNotEquals:
                  s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256


  rLambdaInvokePermission:
    #DependsOn: "int1-draps-us-east-1"
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: us-east-1-upload
      #FunctionName: !GetAtt rUploadLambda.Arn
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !GetAtt rS3bucket.Arn

  rS3bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      BucketName: !Sub ${pAWSAccountLC}-${pParentVPCLC}-${pAppNameLC}-${AWS::Region}
      CorsConfiguration:
        CorsRules:
        - AllowedHeaders: [ChecksumValue, CheckDate]
          AllowedMethods: [GET, PUT, POST, DELETE]
          ExposedHeaders: [ChecksumValue, CheckDate]
          AllowedOrigins: ['*']
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: Transition1day
            Status: Enabled
            Transitions:
              - TransitionInDays: !Ref pS3GLACIERTransitionPeriod
                StorageClass: GLACIER
      **NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
          -
            Event: "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
            Function:
              Fn::ImportValue:
                Fn::Sub: "us-east-1-upload-rUploadLambda"**
```

Comment: Can you paste the error you are getting?